# How to use multiple for loop in ajax.?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I want to create records for just only one time not duplicate. I am trying with multiple `for loop` and its  create two record of same database records, First for loop do this for one time and child / inner for loop do this second time. so record generate duplicate. Any one can help me How can I use two `for loop` condition for a single record.

Here is my code.

```
<script>
function createDiv(data) {
      var dynamicHTML = '';
      var innerContent = '';

      alert(data.res4.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.res2.length; i++) {
      for(var j =0; j< data.res4.length; j++){
                if(data.res2[i].paid_type == 1) {
                    if(data.res3[0].Status == "success") {

                            if(data.res4[j].Status == 'success'){
                              innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">'+
                              '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
                                  '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
                                        '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis</button>' +
                                  '</span>'+
                              '</div>';
                            } else {
                                innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">'+
                                '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +        
                                    '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
                                        '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Take Test </button>' +
                                    '</span>'+
                                '</div>';
                            }
                        }

                 else {
                            innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">'+
                            '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +        
                                '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
                                    '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Buy</button>' +
                                '</span>'+
                            '</div>';               
                    }
                }
                else {          

                            alert(j+ ' j is here');
                                if(data.res4[j].A_Submit_Status == "success"){
                                  innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">'+
                                  '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
                                      '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
                                            '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Analysis 1</button>' +
                                      '</span>'+
                                  '</div>';
                                } else {
                                    innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">'+
                                    '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +        
                                        '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
                                            '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Take Test 1</button>' +
                                        '</span>'+
                                    '</div>';
                                }                               
                        }
                    }   
                }

      dynamicHTML += '<div id="' + data.res2.Paper_Type + '" class="tabcontent" style="border:none;">' + innerContent + '</div>';
      $('div#tabs_data').append(dynamicHTML);
    }
</script>
```

Here is my image of duplicate records.

[image]

I am passing json data from Codeigniter controller..

```
$tabs_data['res2'] = $this->db->select('*')->from('tb1')->where('Paper_Type', $paper_name)->get()->result();
            $tabs_data['res3'] = $this->db->select('*')->from('tb2')->where($UP)->get()->result();
            $tabs_data['res4'] = $this->db->select('*')->from('tb3')->where($PA)->get()->result();
```

**Edited**

IF `paid_type == 1` then it is paid so first check there if user appeared exam then show `Analysis` else show `Buy`

same in below in else part `if(paid_type != 1)` then first check exam appeared then show `Analysis` else show `Take test`

In row Name data comes from `tb1` and Button data comes from `tb3`. Any one can help me on this topic.

json Output

```
{"user":"abc@gmail.com",
    "res2":[{"id":"1","Paper_Name":"sm1","Paper_Type":"ss","paid_type":"0"},{"id":"2","Paper_Name":"    ss-2","Paper_Type":"ss","paid_type":"1"},{"id":"3","Paper_Name":"ss-3","Paper_Type":"ss","paid_type":"1"},{"id":"4","Paper_Name":"ss-4","Paper_Type":"ss","paid_type":"1"}],
    "res3":[{"User_id":"abc@gmail.com","Name":"mahi mahi","Phone":"2147483647","Txnid":"2147483647","Amount":"120","Product_Info":"ss","encryptedPaymentId":"CBEC29993C2DAE0B37453BFAD285CB87","Status":"success","Date_Time":"2017-04-20 12:22:49"}],
    "res4":[{"A_User_id":"abc@gmail.com","A_Paper_Name":"ss-1","A_Paper_Type":"ss","A_Submit_Status":"success","A_Date_Time":"2017-04-21 04:33:11"}]}
```

Comment: Why two for loops? What does your data look like? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @SloanThrasher its because of my controller json data. You can check edited text in question.

Comment: Any one can help me I reaaly need this thing.?

Comment: Maybe if you showed your JSON data, and explained what you are trying to do better.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I edited this with some more ditails you can now check that

Comment: Sample of JSON data? Table schema and relationships? You may be able to use SQL to retrieve the data so it's easier to output.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I post json output please, and don't compare image and output names because I changed database value so..

Comment: Table schema & relationships?

Comment: there is no relationship between this three table. I must use two `for loop` because length of `data.res2` is 4 and `data.res4` is 1..so I cant use `var i` of `data.res2[i] `in `data.res4[]`

Comment: Sure there are. Some are evident in the sample JSON. I suspect your task would be a lot easier if you were able to use a single SQL query. For example, user, res3 and res4 are related on the email address. Res2 is related to res4 on the paper name. Basically, if there are no relationships, you task is FUBAR

Comment: Getting info is like pulling teeth. Maybe someone else with more patience that I apparently have will be able to help you.

Comment: no problem thanks for taking time for me. Now I am trying to create a single sql query. and It's is just only one way.